# PyCharm doesn't recognize packages installed via Terminal when environment is used in PyCharm in Pop_OS Linux

Tags: python, linux, pycharm

I'm using Pop_OS! Linux. Whenever I make a Python Virtual Environment using mkvirtualenv and then pip install packages into it, that environment does not work when I reference it inside pycharm. I set up virtual environments using virtualenv and virtualenvwrapper.

The workaround I've found is to build any virtual environment you need to use inside of PyCharm inside of pycharm, or using the terminal inside of PyCharm. I'm annoyed it doesn't seem compatible with my native terminal, and can't figure out why. I even get slightly different python versions by running `python --version` both inside the PyCharm terminal and in the native linux terminal, while inside the same virtual environment! It's like Pycharm isn't reading the same information out of the python environment directory as my terminal is.

What is going on here, and how do I harmonize PyCharm with the rest of my linux machine? I'm also new to Pop_OS! Trying it out for the first time is an adventure.

Comment: make sure that they are pointing to the same python version...   (quite common).

Comment: @D.L They are pointing to the same version if I run "which python" both inside PyCharm and in my Linux Terminal. I also checked the path in the PyCharm configuration GUI and it matches as well. The path everywhere is: ~/.virtualenvs/hw3pycharm/bin/python

Answer (score 0):

IDK if that will work, but maybe if you install your packages via the "Python packages" tab  in PyCharm (down left -> add package next to the research bar that appeared), PyCharm will see them while it installed them itself.

Comment: Yes, it appears to be something like that. PyCharm can see the packages if I run 'pip install ...' inside the PyCharm terminal tab. That's how I've been using it for now... I'm just annoyed i HAVE to use the terminal inside of PyCharm... seems like the environments should work everywhere. I want to know why they don't.